# Index Match VBA Formula Not Updating to Correct Row

Tags: excel, vba, loops, vba7

My code runs but `MATCH('Worksheets1'!$D2,` is not changing or updating based on the the row it is at.

For example if my worksheet contains 2000 rows to be index matched the formula will still just contain `MATCH('Worksheets1'!$D2` as the cell it is referencing .

How do I make the cell value change based on what what row number the code is at?

```vb
Sub trial()
On Error Resume Next

Dim Dept_Row As Long
Dim Dept_Clm As Long

Table1 = Worksheets1.Range("D:D") 
Table2 = Worksheets2.Range("A:B") 
Dept_Row = Worksheets1.Range("A2").Row 
Dept_Clm = Worksheets1.Range("A2").Column

For Each cl In Table1

    If IsEmpty(cl) Then Exit Sub
                                            
    If Not IsEmpty(cl) Then Worksheets("Worksheets1").Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = _
      "=INDEX('Worksheets2'!$B:$B,MATCH('Worksheets1'!$D2,'Worksheets2'!A:A,0)) "

    Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1

Next cl

Exit Sub
```

I created the loop in hopes of the formula updating giving it the

Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1.

I tried both leaving it where it is, and introducing the code to quotation marks after the formula ended. However, my code is only able to run as is.

I was thinking of doing plus 1 but I doubted that would work it would just turn the cell value of D2 into D3 for all.

Comment: That `On Error Resume Next` is hiding some errors.

Comment: can you explain a bit more on what you mean? I deleted that part and code still ran and tried to debug to see if there were any errors after that portion of the code was delete and I didn't get any just wanted to ask more to check.

Comment: You're missing some `Set`: `Set Table1 = Worksheets1.Range("D:D")` and `Set Table2 = Worksheets2.Range("A:B")`.

Comment: You mean `"=INDEX('Worksheets2'!$B:$B,MATCH('Worksheets1'!$D" & Dept_Row & "'Worksheets2'!A:A,0))"`?

Comment: @findwindow i'd post that as an actual answer so this can be adequately closed... that should be the objective solution, allowing this to be "answered."

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to loop. All of your code can be boiled down to:

```
With Worksheets("worksheet1")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 
    .Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Formula = "=INDEX('Worksheets2'!$B:$B,MATCH(D2,'Worksheets2'!A:A,0))"
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is unclear but I guess this is what you're looking for:

```
"=INDEX('Worksheets2'!$B:$B,MATCH('Worksheets1'!$D" & Dept_Row & "'Worksheets2'!A:A,0))"
```

Comment: Sorry let me see if I can clarify it I am trying to for example if the loop code is in row 1000 the D2 should be D1000 so I am trying to come up with a way to get that to happen. 

Using your suggestion render the code unable to run :( sorry but thank you for your suggestion :).